# Unable to access intranet web site from client machine

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis, routing

I have installed windows 2008 r2 server on a machine with 2 network cards. I am able to access internet from this server. I have installed mysql and mssql 2008 on this machine. I can access both the databases from client machine but I am not able to access website created on this server from client machine. (The default website can be accessed from the client) As trial I assigned port no 85 to the site I created using wordpress. But if I use the server name with portno (http://:85) I can not access the site. I want to make this site available only on intranet.

For one network card I have assigned IP address assigned to me from my ISP. For the other card the IP address is obtained automatically.

Comment: Given that it's dual homed, I'll place my money on this being a routing problem. Please post your routing table along with the IP's you're attempting to access

Comment: Can you show the IIS site bindings? I am inclined to believe you are mixing up your internal and external ip's.